# Haskell big number calculations

Tags: haskell, math

I am trying to do some calculations with big numbers

```
λ: let r  = 291381631919914084
λ: let t = 1165526527679656343
λ: sqrt(4 * r * r - 4 * r + 1 + 8 * t) - 2 * r + 1
1.0
```

the answer should be `8.0000...`
Is there a package that I should be using for such calculations? or is there something I should be doing in prelude?

Comment: When I do your calculations in Python, using the built-in `math.sqrt()` function, I also get the answer `1.0`. However, when I use my own `isqrt()` function that returns the exact integer part of the square root for all nonnegative integers, I get the answer `8`.  It seems there are too many significant digits in the parameter for Haskell's `sqrt` function to handle exactly--it must use the 8-byte floating point type for `sqrt`, just as Python does. Find an exact sqrt function, perhaps named isqrt, for Haskell that handles arbitrary size integers.

Comment: Yep. Looks like floating point imprecision

Comment: Note that `8` is *not* the exact answer for your question, unless you want `sqrt` to return only the integer part of the square root (as my `isqrt` does). The actual mathematical answer is slightly larger than `8`. However, Pythons' extended precision package does return `8.0000000000`.

Comment: In this particular case, you'd do better to rewrite the expression so that it's not so numerically fragile. You have something of the form `sqrt(a*a + b) - a`, which is the same as `b / (sqrt(a*a + b) + a)`. The latter expression is less prone to numerical error (assuming positive `a` and `b`).

Comment: @MarkDickinson, why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @dfeuer: Good question. Done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct answer is indeed very close to `8.0`. You're running into numerical precision issues: the square root is being computed using IEEE 754 ("double precision") binary64 format, and its 53-bit precision isn't sufficient to give an accurate result here.

In more detail: the true value of `sqrt(4 * r * r - 4 * r + 1 + 8 * t)` is, to 50 significant figures:

```
582763263839828175.00000000000000000686385063746811
```

The closest representable IEEE 754 binary64 value to that quantity is:

```
582763263839828224.0
```

... which is off by about 49.0 from the true value. Similarly, the value `2*r` loses precision when converted to floating-point.

You might be tempted to fix this by increasing the precision, but as so often happens in numerical work, in this case it's better to rework the algorithm to avoid (or at least ameliorate) the numerical issues. The value you're computing is of the form `sqrt(a * a + b) - a` (with `a = 2 * r - 1` and `b = 8 * t`). That quantity can be rewritten in the form `b / (sqrt(a * a + b) + a)`, and (assuming that both `a` and `b` are positive), the latter expression will give a more accurate result.

Here's a quick demonstration that the two expressions give the same result.

```
Prelude> let a = 43
Prelude> let b = 7
Prelude> sqrt(a * a + b) - a
8.131845707602992e-2
Prelude> b / (sqrt(a * a + b) + a)
8.131845707603225e-2
```

We're using smaller values of `a` and `b`, so the numerical issues aren't so bad, but note that there's still a discrepancy in the last 4 digits. (The exact value here is `0.081318457076032250005683932322636450`, to 35 significant figures.)

And using this form of the expression with your values:

```
Prelude> let r = 291381631919914084
Prelude> let t = 1165526527679656343
Prelude> let a = 2*r - 1; b = 8*t in b / (sqrt(a*a+b) + a)
8.0
```

As other answerers have pointed out, the answer isn't *exactly* `8.0`, but `8.0` *is* the closest IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point value to the true answer.

Answer (score 7):

I believe `8` is not a correct answer, either; the number you have given is not square:

```
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares> r  = 291381631919914084
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares> t = 1165526527679656343
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares> isSquare (4*r*r - 4*r + 1 + 8*t)
False
```

However, you can get this answer if it's the one you want:

```
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares> integerSquareRoot (4*r*r - 4*r + 1 + 8*t) - 2*r + 1
8
```

The [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.5.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Squares.html) package provides these functions.

Or, you can get as many digits of the exact answer as you like:

```
Data.Number.CReal> sqrt (4*r*r - 4*r + 1 + 8*t) - 2*r + 1 :: CReal
8.0000000000000000068638506374681082902485
```

The [numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-CReal.html) package provides this type.

Answer (score -3):

I put these numbers and formula in Rstudio and also got 1. Are you sure the answer is 8? Maybe add more parentheses to make sure you got your order of operation correct.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what means "more parentheses".